# Existence of an inverse when verifying whether $\mathbb R^3$ forms a group under this operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

How do I approach finding the inverse of a group? The question is as follows:

$G= (x_1,y_1,z_1) \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Is $(G,*)$ a group?
Where multiplication is defined as
$(x_1,y_1,z_1)*(x_2,y_2,z_2) = (x_1 + x_2 ,y_1 + x_1z_2+y_2,z_1 + z_2)$

I was able to show non-empty, associativity, commutativity and the identity element, $(0,0,0)$. However I cannot come up with an inverse. Is there no inverse for this question?

Comment: $(x_1,x_2,x_3)*(0,0,0)=(x_1,y_1+x_1z_1,z_1)$, so $(0,0,0)$ is not an identity element.

Comment: "inherited from $\Bbb{R}^3$" ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I made a typo, it is actually $y_1+x_1z_2$ so it should hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inverse, you can solve directly $$\left\{\begin{align}&x_1+x_2=0\\
&y_1+x_1z_2+y_2=0\\
&z_1+z_2=0
\end{align}\right.$$
for $x_2$, then $z_2$, then $y_2$.

> We find $x_2=-x_1$, $z_2=-z_1$ and finally $y_2=-y_1+x_1z_1$.

Comment: This makes so much sense now. I wasn't thinking about it this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is this really a group? If $e=(a,b,c)$ identity element than we have $$x_1+a=x_1\implies a=0$$
$$y_1+x_1z_1 +b = y_1\implies b= -x_1z_1$$
$$ z_1+c = z_1\implies c=0$$

So $a$ and $c$ are defined, but $b$ is not unique, it depends on $x_1$ and $z_1$. This should not be.

Comment: Sorry I actually made a typo in the question. It should be $ (x_1 + x_2 ,y_1 + x_1z_2+y_2,z_1 + z_2)$

Answer (score 1):

We have a bijection between $\mathbb R^3$ and unipotent upper-triangular matrices by sending
$$(x,y,z) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1&x&y\\0&1&z\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
You can verify that under this bijection, $*$ is just matrix multiplication. The inverse of an invertible upper-triangular matrix is upper-triangular<sup>(1)</sup>, and the inverse of a unipotent matrix is unipotent.

<sup>(1)</sup> An invertible filtered homomorphism on a finite-dimensional filtered vector space is a filtered isomorphism, or see [Inverse of an invertible upper triangular matrix of order 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003801) if you like computations.